# How To make similar Material UI Gmail Tasks Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

Hi I was wondering how to replicate a similar style as the new Gmail Tasks app. The new Gmail UI is based on Material Design.

Since I'm making a Gmail Add-on with React & InboxSDK, I'd like to replicate the look & feel. I am currently using this Material UI component library: https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/

I am assuming that it is accomplished by putting a `select` as first component in the toolbar: https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/

[Gmail App "Keep" Toolbar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ2as.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking for, but if it's just the CSS needed to make something like your screenshot, then maybe this will help:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wuas6p

I'm using the CSS library styled-components, in case you don't want to deal with Material-UI's javascript in CSS.

Comment: Great, thanks! I can work with that. I played around with React's Material UI but couldn't quite get it right with the input field and label above.